# JCheckBox not being rendered within JTable (JRE?)

Tags: jtable, render, jcheckbox

I have a Jtable and intend to add JCheckboxes to it. There is quite a clear example
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which I implemented yet kept on getting "true" and "false" String values when running. I then tried to run the example itself and discovered that it too is displaying "true"/"false" string values.

[image]

Is this a problem with my JRE? How can I be able to view/work with checkboxes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure to override this function in your table model?  This is what tells the table that those values are `Booleans`.

```
 @Override
 public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
    return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
 }
```